# Sandboxed `this` in Firefox WebExtension content script

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

The following code:

```
(function(local_window) {
  local_window.example = 1234;
  console.log(window);
  console.log(local_window);
}(this));
console.log(this);

console.log(window.example);
console.log(example);
```

Prints (as expected) the following:

```
Window
Window
Window
1234
1234
```

When:

- run in a webpage on Firefox and Chrome
- run in a Firefox Addon-SDK content script
- run in a Chrome WebExtension content script

However, in a Firefox WebExtension content script this prints the following:

```
Window
Sandbox { browser: Getter, chrome: Getter, example: 1234, browser: Object, chrome: Object, window: Window → /, document: HTMLDocument → /, location: Location → /, top: Window → /, self: Window → /, 72 more }
Sandbox { browser: Object, chrome: Object, example: 1234, window: Window → /, document: HTMLDocument → /, location: Location → /, top: Window → /, self: Window → /, name: "", history: History, 72 more }
undefined
1234
```

`example !== window.example` was a very weird surprise then porting the Chrome extension to FF. Is this an intended breakage (or a bug)? Is this documented anywhere? I don't see it in the [MDN compatibility notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Chrome_incompatibilities).

Context: I was using [zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/zepto.js) (which installs itself into `this.$`) in a content script and one piece of code was accessing it with `window.$`, which failed on FF.

Answer (score 1):

This is deliberate, and it is documented at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Accessing_page_script_objects_from_content_scripts

Comment: I'm not 100% it's related, or if it is, intentional (or if it is, properly documented). The page is about page script objects visibility in content script context, but I don't do anything with page scripts, it's just about `x === this.x !== window.x` in a content script. That's also why `wrappedJSObject` is unrelated.
(I added some extra context in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this behavior is contrary to Firefox's documentation and a compatibility issue, so I filed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1607242